# Xamarin iOS Linking Failed Problem While Building

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The application is ready for Xamarin IOS.
Yesterday there was no problem. I did visual studio update for hot restart to 16.7.3.
Today when I turn it on, I am remote to the mac, but when I say build, I get linking failed errors like the following, about 33.
I haven't installed any nuget packages etc.
**It took me a day to undo the last changes I made.
It builds when not connected to the Mac but when I connect to the mac I get these errors anyway.
I can't figure it out. Can you help me?**

This is the project output while building:

```
2>  takikuyumculuk.iOS -> C:\Users\Onur\source\repos\takikuyumculuk\takikuyumculuk\takikuyumculuk.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Release\takikuyumculuk.iOS.exe
2>  Detected signing identity:
2>          
2>    Bundle Id: com.takikuyumculuk.apple
2>    App Id: com.takikuyumculuk.apple
2>  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/takikuyumculuk/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/takikuyumculuk.iOS/9d7e2ac1ac9741d6ee40a3186654ad40/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Release/response-file.rsp "--gcc_flags=-ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz" 
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULIsLoggableLevel. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULLogBasic. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULLogError. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULLogInfo. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULLogWarning. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULSetLoggerLevel. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GULAppDelegateSwizzler. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppDelegateSwizzler' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GULAppEnvironmentUtil. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GULMutableDictionary. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULMutableDictionary' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GULNetwork. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULNetwork' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GULSwizzler. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULSwizzler' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeCannotAcceptTraffic. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotFound. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotModified. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeUnavailable. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kGULNetworkHTTPStatusNoContent. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kGULNetworkHTTPStatusOK. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_decode. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_decode_varint. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_encode. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_encode_string. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_encode_submessage. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_encode_tag_for_field. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_encode_varint. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_istream_from_buffer. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_ostream_from_buffer. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _pb_read. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System.Net.Security' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'dl' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error : ] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_87bdad44f2b9aa68c2d607a36be1b8c5.o)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error : ] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_87bdad44f2b9aa68c2d607a36be1b8c5.o)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error : ] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_87bdad44f2b9aa68c2d607a36be1b8c5.o)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error : ] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_87bdad44f2b9aa68c2d607a36be1b8c5.o)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the image of errors:

[image]

Comment: Friends, it is about a project that needs an urgent catch. There was no problem, it turned out at once. I can't build the iOS project right now :(

Comment: Hi, you could have a try with checking the [Link SDK assemblies only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#link-sdk-assemblies-only) whehter can solve this problems.

Comment: Thanks for your interest :)) I removed a nuget package which causes the error problem solved :)

Comment: Okey, glad have solved that! You can update this in answer when you have time, then others who occurs the same problem will know how to solve that.

Comment: Could you please explain which kind of nuget you removed? I've the exact same situation in a pretty large project and can't figure that out... Link sdk assemblies only didn't solve :(

Comment: A nuget package incompatible with your project.Maybe you should review the packages you add or update to new version.